# data fields or local variables whose value cannot be modified?

Tags: c#

Hey guys I am brand new to c#. I was reading this book and this fill in the blanks says  __ are the data fields or local variables whose values cannot be modifed? Can someone tell me the answer? thanks. 
ps: total newbie I searched youtube but I was messed up in code.
thanks.

Comment: Constants can be the answer.

Comment: @Yoda only for primitive types though

Comment: @Yoda Not if your search engine is Youtube

Comment: `readonly` is also the correct answer. Since the question is stated as "are the data fields **or** local variables". Readonly can't be used for local variables, but can be used for fields, so *or* condition isn't violated. The difference between const and readonly is that you can assign readonly fields in ctor. They are not compile time constants, while const are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is Const. 
here is the link [Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The complete answer is twofold:

1) For primitive types (such as `int`, `double`, `string`, etc.) a `const` modifier can be used, which indeed means that the value of the variable of this type cannot be changed by any means

2) For non-primitive types a `readonly` modifier exists. Note, that you cannot apply `const` to non-primitive types. It means the same thing for reference and value types: the
 *reference* to this variable cannot be changed after the construction of *this* object.
However, it has different consequences:

2.1) The `readonly` object itself can be changed by means of it's public API. For example:

```
class Foo{
  private readonly List<int> list;
  public Foo(){ list = new List<int>();}

  public Test()
  {
    list = new List<int>(); // invalid; your reference is readonly
    list.add(5);//works, you are changing the object, but not touching it's reference
  }
}
```

2.2) For value types `readonly` one must be careful while using `readonly` modifier -  it may lead to subtle errors with mutable structs. See [C#: Why do mutations on readonly structs not break?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859534/c-why-do-mutations-on-readonly-structs-not-break) for example. However, if your `struct` is immutable you effectively get the semantics of `const` keyword

Comment: `readonly` can be used for non-primitive types. Both keywords work the same way for values and reference types and their semantics doesn't change depending of the type of a variable.

Comment: the consequenses for programmer do change. You don't have problems with  mutable classes, but you do have them with mutable structs

Comment: `You don't have problems with mutable classes` depends on your intention. If I mark reference variable with readonly I may suppose it won't be changed, but if an object is mutable of that type - I might be very wrong.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I am mentioning this in my answer. The thing is that readonly != const by any means, which I tried to emphasise

Comment: totally agree. From my side I just wanted to note, that `readonly` behaves exactly the same for value and reference types. As well as `const` behaviour doesn't change for value and reference types.